# How to allow users to be able to upload to my google drive in rails app and then provide them a preview link for google doc in the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I need my rails app users to be able to upload to my google drive folder. He should click browse file button and after submission, the file should be uploaded to my drive and I should be able to get document preview link and download link for the user in the rails app itself. Please tell me how to proceed with this. I am completely new to rails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gem paperclip` which is Easy file attachment management for ActiveRecord

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

and then use `paperclip-googledrive` extension gem to upload file to google drive

https://github.com/evinsou/paperclip-googledrive

Comment: Thanks Ashish...can i also get preview link and download link of drive document, so that I can show it in view of rails app.???

Comment: Not sure about the preview but yes you will get the download link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem `google-api-client` and use one of its classes `DriveService` of `DriveV3`, you can find its documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/DriveV3). There you should find how to give access to your drive.

Create a `DriveV3::DriveService` instance:

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v3'
drive_service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
# ... refer to doc to provide authorization ...
```

you have to save the file in your server and provide that file for GoogleApi to read from and create it. In this method I am creating this local file from a DataURL string and the same file as a source for DriveService:

```
# 'content' is a dataURL string representing the file's content
# 'folder_id' is the id of the drive's folder to create the file into
file_metadata = {
  name: 'my_file_name.pdf',
  parents: [folder_id],
  description: 'This is my file'
}
Tempfile.open(local_filename) do |f|
  f.binmode 
  f.write(URI::Data.new(content).data)
  file = drive_service.createfile(metadata, upload_source: f, fields: 'id')
  # file will contain the id that google created for it
end
```

To get a small image of the file:

```
file = drive_service.get_file 'your_file_id', fields: 'thumbnailLink'
# => <Google::Apis::DriveV3::File:0x000000 @thumbnail_link="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...">
```

The content of `file.thumbnail_link` can be inserted into a normal `<img src=>` tag and displayed.

There is the property `webViewLink` that will open the file completely in the browser. You can ask for it also in the parameter fields: `webViewLink,thumbnailLink,id`.

If you want, you can make one single GoogleAPI request to create the file and receive its thumbnailLink by including `thumbnailLink` into the parameter `fields` of the function `create_file`.